# VB Compare two range of cells in multiple workbooks and if match copy to different cell

Tags: vba, excel, compare

I am trying to figure this out all day. This is what I need to accomplish:

1. Using GetFile select a number of workbooks without opening them.
2. Compare Cell A2 of selected workbooks indiviually in loop to a reference workbook.
3. If Cell A2 of the selected workbook equals the numerical value of the numerical value within the reference workbook contained within column A then copy/past column B's text in the corresponding cell of the matched reference workbook cell  to M2 of the selected workbook.

Sounds complicated but let me demonstrate. The letters represent column names.

Selected Workbook
A2=12   M2= ""

Reference Workbook
A2=12   B2=milk, protein

Desired result:
Selected Workbook
A2=12   M2=milk, protein

So far this is the code I have:

```
Sub Click() 
Dim rCell As Range, vVal1, vVal2 
Dim wbCheck As Workbook 

For Each rCell In Workbooks("2.xls").Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C100") 
    vVal1 = rCell 
    vVal2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(rCell.Address) 
    If IsNumeric(vVal1) And IsNumeric(vVal1) Then 
        If vVal1 = vVal2 Then 
            rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 
        ElseIf vVal1 < > vVal2 Then  
        End If 
    End If 
Next rCell 
End Sub
```

Comment: Where does MS Access come into the story? Also, where are you running into a problem?

Comment: If your reference values are in Column A, why are you also comparing values in columns B and C ? In your sample code is `ThisWorkbook` the "reference" workbook?

Comment: Are the cells contiguous in both sheets? if so you can save data to arrays and compare then do a full dump to the new sheet.

Comment: @Tim. I cant divulge why to your question

Comment: @Remou sames message as Tim

Comment: @bonCodigo Can you provide an example?

Comment: You seem to be saying you're not prepared to answer any questions about your current code?  That's a strange position to take here...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a VBA code for this?

This can be achieved using an Excel Formula.

Paste this in `M2` and copy it down

```
=IF(A2='C:\[Ref.xlsx]Sheet1'!A2,'C:\[Ref.xlsx]Sheet1'!B2,"")
```

**My Assumptions** (Please change as applicable)

1. The reference file name is Ref.xlsx
2. You are pulling data from `Sheet1` of reference file
3. The Ref.xlsx is in C:

**EDIT**

Even if you want to use VBA, you can also do this.

```
Sub Sample()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M2").Formula = _
    "=IF(A2='C:\[Sample.xlsx]Sheet1'!A2,'C:\[Sample.xlsx]Sheet1'!B2,"""")"

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

The above formula or code is beneficial becuase of what you mentioned in 1st point `Using GetFile select a number of workbooks without opening them.` If you do not want to open the file then the `formula` or `formula in VBA` is the way to go :)

Comment: Siddharth, Thanks for your helpful feedback. Two issues actually. If a use the formula in excel everytime I press enter it brings up the find link dialog box for the reference workbook location. Second, I want to use the range of B2:B1923 to see if there is a match with A2 of the selected sheet and then copy the match contained within the range of G2:I1923 of the reference file inclusively. Any further advise?

Comment: To my previous comment. It is the Lookup ISReference dialog box that opens which is similar to the find link dialog box. Either way I do not want this to open. Here is what I have so far.... M2=IF(H2= 'C:\Desktop\Merge\[ISReference.xlsx]Reference]Reference!'$B$2:$B$1923,'C:\Desktop\Merge\[ISReference.xlsx]Reference]Reference!'$G$2:$I$1923,"No Match")  This wont work...Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question. The answer was to use VLookup.

=VLOOKUP(I2, 'C:\Desktop\Merge[ISReference.xlsx]Reference'!B2:G1923, 6, FALSE)

I am surprised no one suggested this to me. Given its simplicity I was able to build this function into some code I built to run through a FSO filedialog picker on a form in access and link external workbooks with Vlookup.

Thanks Siddarth for giving the proper direction of embedding a function instead of crazy iterated loop.